# Reducing the size of pdf generated from software using proprietary fonts

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, flash, hindi

I am trying to bring an Indian Magazine online. This magazine is typed in CorelDraw using the proprietary `Devenagari` font (http://www.modular-infotech.com/html/shreelipi.html). So these guys have provided a USB dongle that you have to have attached to the machine when you want to access the fonts, and this software has been in use for past 10 years.

To put the magazine online, we've tried to convert it to pdf (by printing). The resultant pdf size is of the order of 30-50MB, even when the pdf does not have even a single image. I am guessing it converts the whole text into an image

It would be really difficult for users to read this magazine given its size. Though when I convert it to .swf format (for add flipbook kind of functionality) - the size reduces to 5-6MB. But there are people who like to download the magazine and then read. I have had no luck reducing the size of pdf.

I have done lot of research on web. The postscript, primo pdf do not help much. The best I could get was 30% reduction using DocuCom pdf printer. But it is still 20MB. I have tried to play with resolution, compression and quality but the best I could get was 18MB.

Ideally I would like to reduce it to less than 2MB.

I would be really grateful if you could help me reduce the size of the pdf! Considering that it has no images, I am hopeful that I can get some really good compression.

The (35MB) magazine can be downloaded from: http://merajhola.in/jin-march.pdf

Comment: A copy-protection dongle for _fonts_? Yikes. What is it about this font that means you have to use it? What format are they in - TrueType? How many pages does the 35M PDF contain? (I'm certainly not downloading it)! Are you embedding a subset of the fonts you use, or all of them?

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any easy way to reduce the size of this PDF. There are no embedded fonts and all the text is drawn using vector graphics primitives. No amount of tweaking the resolution, compression and quality will have a significant improvement.

One possible option would be to embed the font as a subset rather than use vector graphics. That will almost certainly make a big difference, however I doubt the proprietary font license will allow it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but this Shree-Lipi thing just sounds *wrong* in 2012. It would be much better to use proper OpenType fonts with modern (say InDesign) or free (say LuaTeX) software.